# Laravel orderBy hasMany Relationship

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

my next problem is to order items which have hasMany Relationship and the ordering field is in the Relationship.

I have table: country, which has only the ID field
i have also table: country_translation, which has columns: name, lang

in my CountryController in the index()-method i want to show all countries for the default language sort them by parameter name and paginate them.

Here is my Country Model:

```
class Country extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'code', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'currency_id', 'timezone', 'dam_date', 'status',
    ];

    public function translations() {

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CountryTranslation');

    }
}
```

CountryTranslation Model:

```
class CountryTranslation extends Model {

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'lang', 'country_id',
    ];

    public function country() {
        return $this->hasOne('Country');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I undestood you correctly, this should work:

```
$countries = CountryTranslation::where('lang', 'en')->orderBy('name')->paginate(20)
```